# java: UTF-32 to UTF-16 convertor

Tags: java, utf-8, utf-32

I'm trying to get the java escape code.
**Example**: `1F612` ==> `\ud83d\ude12`

I tried:

```
String toConvert = "\ud83d\ude12";
String result = "";
for(int x=0;x<toConvert.length();x++){
    int codePoint = Character.codePointAt(toConvert, x);
    String hexStr = Integer.toHexString(codePoint);
    hexStr = formatUTF(hexStr);
    result += hexStr;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

formatUTF function:

```
public static String formatUTF(String hex){
    String text = hex;
    for(int x = 0; x<4-hex.length();x++)
        text = "0"+text;
    return "\\u"+text;
}
```

but the output:

```
run:
\u1f612\ude12
```

**Note**: `1F612` Hex = `128530` Integer

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this clarifies all.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < toConvert.length(); ) {
        int codePoint = Character.codePointAt(toConvert, i);
        i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
        System.out.printf("[%d] cp: %x%n", i, codePoint);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < toConvert.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = toConvert.charAt(i);
        System.out.printf("[%d] c: %x%n", i, (int)ch);
    }
```

It yields one single code point of two 16 bit chars.

```
    [2] cp: 1f612
    [0] c: d83d
    [1] c: de12
```

Exactly as the [UTF-16 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) says.

Comment: thanx. this what i'm looking for. so, i was using the wrong function. :p